# MVC4 C# and KnockoutJS. Initializing ko.observable with C# value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-mvc

Is there a possibility to write a C# variable into ko.observable() variable?
For instance, i have two radio buttons(true and false) with "data-bind="checked: isEvent". I need to initialize this ko.observable - "isEvent" value, with @Model.isEvent right before rendering those two radiobuttons, to get proper radiobutton checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can serialize your model into a single variable in the head of your document, and then access properties that way, so that you don't have to include your entire view model in your view.

Based on your comments, here is a more complete example of how this would work.

In your layout page:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
<!-- this should already be referenced in your project, but if not use Nuget to install it -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var model = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
        //Alternatively, you can omit any serialization, and just use:
        var isEvent = @Model.isEvent;
    </script>
    <script src="path_to_view_model.js"></script>
</head>
```

In your KO view model:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.isEvent = ko.observable(model.isEvent);
}
```

Comment: I don't need to serialize whole object, i need just a single field. Also this is in the View (not Main layout), so i actualy don't have a "head" there.

Comment: I have a slight problem with declaring this in Master Layout, because Model is not always of type, that has isEvent field.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably want to make use of @RenderSection(). In your layout page, you would do something like @RenderSection("head", false) in the head section of your document. The false parameter makes it so that section isn't required. Then in your view, you can use @section { ... }, and any code in there will be inserted into the <head> of your document

Comment: But that's the advantage of serializing your whole model, instead of just the variable you need. Even if your model is null, JsonConvert.SerializeObject() will just output var model = null; You can then use Javascript to test for whether something is defined or not. Additionally, if you end up needing access to more variables, or complex data structures, then you'll end up making less modifications to your code later on. The exception to this is if your model contains large data structures that would unnecessarily increase load time.

Comment: Finaly i got this working :) And thanks for information about @RenderSection. It was first time i met this helper. Pretty handy :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

```
isEvent = ko.observable(@Model.isEvent);
```

This will generate the following javascript:

```
isEvent = ko.observable(true);
```

Comment: Where shall i put this definition?

Comment: In whatever Javascript code you have that you need to initialize it.